# Node4j retrieve nodes grouped by least specific group

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I’m new to Neo4j and I need to prototype something for yesterday. I’m still considering using a conventional relational database for doing this unless you can clearly demonstrate how convenient it is using a graph db for this specific application.

Suppose I have this chart:
[image: Graph example]

B has parent A
C has parent A
D has parent A
E has parent B
F has parent C
G has parent C
H has parent C
I has parent D

I need to retrieve the current node + 1 level grouped by the largest group of nodes as possible.

My result for node A:
[image: A result]

My result for Group 1:
[image: Group 1 result]

And so on...

I'm starting from scratch so all your suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To model this hierarchy, you need a defined relation type that allows us to pick out what are the children of what.   So let's assume a setup like this:

```
CREATE (a:Node { name: 'a' }), (b:Node { name: 'b' }), 
       (c:Node { name: 'c' }), (d:Node { name: 'd' }),
       (e:Node { name: 'e' }), (f:Node { name: 'f' }), 
       (g:Node { name: 'g' }), (h:Node { name: 'h' }),
       (i:Node { name: 'i' }),
       (a)-[:child]->(b), (a)-[:child]->(c);
/* And so on for all relationships */
```

Querying for a group is a very straightforward process of just traversing `:child` links, like this:

```
MATCH (a:Node { name: 'a' })-[:child*]->(groupMember:Node)
RETURN groupMember;
```

The magic here is just the `*` which allows you to match any number of relationship hops.  As long as your graph has no cycles, this will always give you the complete set of descendant nodes in a hierarchy.

You can get pretty fancy from there -- limit the path length to only fetch n levels of hierarchy, impose extra conditions on what the children can be, or match this to a path and return the path through the graph rather than the nodes themselves, whatever you like.

Comment: thanks, this is a very decent start for me. Could you please give me an example that will output A children's in this format: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgEi5.png ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that format.  If you use the query provided, in the neo4j browser you should see something similar.  But your options for output from cypher are tabular data like CSV, or that visual graph.

Comment: Can you please check this question. Maybe its more obvious what I'm trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136299/neo4j-grouping-with-two-relationships